# Not able to exec into container

Tags: containers, containerd

I am not able to exec into container which uses containerd as runtime.

I need to check some processes running inside the container. Is there any way to exec into container?

I am able to list containers using ctr cli.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't have much experience but containerd as runtime but with docker, the exited process don't show up in the `docker ps` command and need to explicit add `-a` flag as `docker ps -a`. Could you verify that the container process is still running? if you are just asking about the docker command (I assume not), `docker exec` is what is used for `exec`ing into the containers.

Comment: I don't know anything about docker, but searching for `docker how to exec into a container` gives a lot of results.

Comment: Containers are up and running . As  they use containerd as runtime I didn't find any way to exec into container.

Comment: There is typically a higher level tool (like Docker) in front of containerd. Are you running Docker in this environment? Or something else? Absent any other solution, you can use `nsenter` to run commands inside a container namespace.

Comment: Is this a question about docker? You've indicated you are trying to use ctr, but tagged the question with docker.

Comment: A container normally runs only one process; if the container is running, its process is too.

Answer (score 9):

`exec` is a sub-command of command `task`,try

```
ctr -a $CONTAINERD_HOST -n $NAMESPACE t exec -t --exec-id $exec_id --fifo-dir /tmp $executor_id bash
```

Comment: What the env vars mean ? Could you elaborate the answer, please ?

Comment: Please explain in details. what is exec_id means?

Comment: I believe `$exec_id` can be set to any value you please; the help for `task exec` describes it as `exec specific id for the process`. In my testing, the value was not important. Presumably it is used for logging somewhere in the cgroup infrastructure.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to the `ctr` command that K D Singh wrote about is `crictl`, so you can use it like so

```sh
crictl exec -it 9b47589560c6d /bin/sh
```

where `9b47589560c6d` would be replaced by your container id (doesn't work with names as far as I know).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly run to learn container id:

> sudo crictl ps -a

[image]

Be careful to use container id (first three letters enough):

> sudo crictl exec -it 27e /bin/sh

[image]

With ctrctl, we can give seperate commands for images, container and pod (like rmi: remove image, rmp: remove pod, rm: remove container)

Commands: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cri-tools/blob/master/docs/crictl.md

Answer (score -1):

Use exec command for containerd

```
ctr containers exec -h
```

Reference:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/docker/containerd/+/refs/tags/v0.2.7/docs/cli.md#exec-another-process-into-a-container

Answer (score -2):

You can use exec command

```
docker exec -it <container name> /bin/sh
```

The -i option keeps the STDIN open and -t allocates a pseudo-tty

This will open the shell and you can execute any command inside the running container.

Comment: This is a great answer for a system that uses docker, but the original poster mentioned that they were using containerd (which is used by rancher), which doesn't have the docker command.